# Checkout stuck step 2 (payment)

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.1.0

I have magento 2 running on live project and our clients are seeing some weird issue on Firefox browser and Chrome as well. I was able to reproduce it only once and after refreshing the page everything is working as expected. I will be happy if someone have/had similar issue and have some information how to debug/fix it.

**Preconditions**

1. Magento CE 2.1.0
2. Production mode & Varnish
3. Firefox latest version & Chrome latest versions

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Add product to basket
2. Navigate to checkout page
3. Enter billing address and select shipping method
4. Click Next button to open payment section

**Expected result:**

Display loader icon, load payment section and cart summary, hide loader icon

**Actual results:**

Display loader icon, load payment section and cart summary, loader icon doesn't hide and stay.

No JS errors on console or network tab in FF (ajax request to getting payment section). After refresh with #payment in URL everything is working fine. Even if open /checkout without #payment (start from 1st step) it's opening 2nd step smoothly.

**I raised issue in github**: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7186

Comment: Can you please try to disable your Payment & Shipping Method & Use the basic Bank Transfer & Free Shipping. Let me know if any progress

Comment: It's not related with the payment or shipping method. We had this issue on staging environment with flat rate and check/ money order. See the link to the github issue. Others are having similar issue not only on FF but in Chrome and Safari too.

Comment: Noted @Miroslav. Eyes on Github Now

Comment: My thinking goes to Varnish. It's Caching Issue i think. Can u disable cache & Check with Magento Default Cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is still not fixed but there is a workaround from [@dcabrejasazagra](https://github.com/dcabrejasazagra) [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7186)

## Workaround:

Override [`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js#L57) into your theme

`magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js`

Inside this file you will find `fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();` called on done and fail methods

So you need to replace them with `fullScreenLoader.stopLoader(true);` which will force stop the loader and resolve the issue.

`stopLoader()` method is defined in [`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/full-screen-loader.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/full-screen-loader.js#L29)

Edit: I assume that some component fails on the checkout and trigger .fail() method but the error processor is not handling errors correctly and display errors and hides the loader.